# How to write below query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am migrating procedure from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. I can not write this query in PostgreSQL. How to use temp within WITH clause in PostgreSQL?

```
WITH TEMP AS
    (
        SELECT a.AssignNo as LowestAssignNo
             , a.AssignNo
             , a.AssignName
             , HierarchyLevel
             , UpperAssignNo 
          FROM TAssignInfo a
         WHERE DeleteYesNo = 'N'
           AND UseYesNo = 'Y'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT a.LowestAssignNo
             , b.AssignNo
             , b.AssignName
             , b.HierarchyLevel
             , b.UpperAssignNo
          FROM TEMP a
        INNER JOIN TAssignInfo b
           ON a.UpperAssignNo = b.AssignNo
        WHERE DeleteYesNo = 'N'
           AND UseYesNo = 'Y'

    )
    SELECT DISTINCT LowestAssignNo
         , STUFF(( SELECT '|' + AssignName
                     FROM TEMP A
                    WHERE a.LowestAssignNo = b.LowestAssignNo 
                      AND HierarchyLevel > 1
                    ORDER BY HierarchyLevel
                     FOR XML PATH('')
                  ), 1, 1, '') AS AssignNamePath
      INTO #NewAssignInfo
      FROM TEMP B    
     WHERE B.HierarchyLevel <> 0
     ORDER BY LowestAssignNo DESC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xojl5.png)

Comment: Start it as follows:  `with recursive temp as (`

Comment: Common table expressions work pretty much the same in Postgres. However the `recursive` keyword is required for recursive CTEs (as defined in the SQL standard) which is [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE). There is also no `stuff()` function in Postgres. What does that do?